# Why did MW3 visits counter stop while Skyrim counter is still working?

Tags: discussion

Why was MW3 Q&A site visit counter stopped on 15.11, while Skyrim counter still works? That's unfair to MW3 players. The counters should be restarted now.

Answer (score 11):

As per the [rules](http://skyrimvsmw3.com/rules):

> **Nov 8 12:00 AM UTC – Nov 15 12:00 AM UTC for Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3**

Each game had 7 days from release to receive questions, answers, and views. Those 7 days are up.

Comment: That's a pity, maybe MW3 would have some chances to catch up. Buhahaha :D

Comment: I think we could leave MW3's counter on for... oh... ever, and it probably wouldn't ever catch up.

Answer (score 7):

Because the MW3 counter started before the Skyrim one did. Both are being given the same amount of days - seven.